Wireguard VPN traffic
I have the following set up:
a peer (my local pc)
a server running wireguard with a bunch of servers behind.
I can connect to each server and all is fine. However i would like to extend this by redirecting some http traffic from one of those servers behind the wireguard server to my local pc (peer). I am not finding any solution on how to achieve this.

What do you mean exactly? Let's say for example you have a server X running HTTP server. Do you want to redirect traffic from the X server port 443 to some port on your local PC through Wireguard? Do I understand correctly?
